# How should I respond to meeting historical sexual abuser in workplace?

Tags: sexual-harassment

I was sexually abused as a fifteen-year-old boy by a large group of peers.

I recently applied for a job at a company where one of my sexual abusers works. I'm unhappy about the prospect of meeting this person, and not sure how I would/should react on meeting them.  In the long term, there is a significant prospect of meeting these people because they are dotted throughout all the sectors I would realistically want to work for - big4, biglaw, corporates, government etc.

What can/should I do in this situation?  How should I handle being forced to work alongside one of my abusers?

Comment: Do you want to at some point report this abuse to anyone, or do you want to keep it unreported?

Comment: I'm very sorry for your experience. Have the statute of limitations expired for your locale? You can find the info for the US here https://www.rainn.org/state-state-guide-statutes-limitations

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I don't think we should be answering this here. This is a question you should ask a mental health professional (if you want to know how to handle it at a personal level) or a lawyer (if you want to to pursue this legally). Random strangers with no expertise are the wrong people to ask about this.

Comment: You deal with the personal issue first and the work second. There is no time limit on historical sexual abuse, deal with that first. Forget the work until you have done that.

Answer (score 2):

> What can/should I do in this situation?

From a workplace perspective, treat them like anybody else you have just met. Any different behavior will come back to you. If you talk to people about why you treat those differently, it will be a huge defamation lawsuit waiting to happen and if you don't, people will think you are just moody or unfair or abusive yourself. You don't have to go out of your way to be nice to them, but you will need to treat them at least with professional respect, like you would treat someone you cannot stand for any other reason but have to work with anyway.

> How should I handle being forced to work alongside one of my abusers?

You should seek professional mental health help. I know the above paragraph is easily written but probably very hard to live. But you don't have to do that on your own. Get help.

Comment: This amounts to blaming the victim. Got abused? Tough luck, get mental health help.

Comment: @Jeffrey I don't understand. Should I advise victims to behave in way that gets them fired and sued? To not get help? If you have different advice, feel free to write an answer that is better than mine, but I really don't see how I'm blaming anything here on anybody. The situation is as it is and since it cannot be changed it has to be navigated as good as possible.

Comment: If truthful, telling HR "Please avoid me working with/for X, as they abused me when I was 15 year old" should definitely be repercussion-free. If truthful, the parties at risk of being sued, here, are in this order: the abuser, the company and the OP, last. I don't know, maybe Germany is behind the times. In Canada, the company would rather employ you in a role were you don't interact with abuser than air the story further. And OP might happen to be the nth person that reports this and cause change to happen.

Comment: Claiming someone committed a heinous crime without any proof might not be a very good move. HR is not your friend, HR is not there to protect you. HR is there to make sure the company does not get into trouble and the fastest way to do that might be to get rid of the person with the unproven allegations. I'm not saying that is fair or right or that I support that, but there is a good chance it would happen. This site is not about what *should* happen in a fair world, but what *will* happen in the world we have right now.

Comment: And even if you are correct and you have a perfect HR, there is no way they can erect an electrified barb-wire fence to make 100% sure that those two will never meet, not even in the restroom, canteen or elevator. So I still think that "get professional help" is good advice, with both handling HR and meeting said abuser.